# How to find out the tables that take up maximum memory in database?

Tags: database, database-design, mysql

Hi I am new to databases. I am working on huge database and trying to clear up the mess. I want to start by finding the top ten tables that take up highest memory in the whole database. I cannot go by finding memory of each table since there are too many tables. I need the top 10 or 20 tables that take up the maximum space. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want memory consumption or disk space ???

Comment: I want disk space and memory consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyISAM only takes up memory for its indexes

To find the top 10 MyISAM tables that can use the most memory in the worst case try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema,table_name,index_length
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
    ORDER BY index_length DESC
) LIMIT 10;
```

InnoDB takes up memory for its data and indexes

To find the top 10 InnoDB tables that can use the most memory in the worst case try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema,table_name,data_length+index_length tblsize
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE engine='InnoDB'
    ORDER BY index_length DESC
) LIMIT 10;
```

Here is another display of the top 50 tables by size descending

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TN TableName,LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(TS/POWER(1024,1),2),',',''),Z,' ') KB,
LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(TS/POWER(1024,2),2),',',''),Z,' ') MB,
LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(TS/POWER(1024,3),2),',',''),Z,' ') GB
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) TN,
(data_length+index_length) TS FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
AND engine IS NOT NULL) A,(SELECT 13 Z) B ORDER BY TS DESC) MMM LIMIT 50;
```

If you are interested, I have queries that give you the whole story on the MySQL Instance

This query shows you the amount of disk space taken by Storage Engine in GB

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine",
CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),
' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size",
CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),
' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(
FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',
SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size"
FROM (SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,
SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')
AND engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY engine WITH ROLLUP) B,(SELECT 3 pw) A ORDER BY TSize;
```

This query shows you the amount of disk space taken by Database in GB

```
SELECT DBName,CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(SDSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),
' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size",CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(SXSize/
POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size",
CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(STSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',
SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Total Size" FROM
(SELECT IFNULL(DB,'All Databases') DBName,SUM(DSize) SDSize,
SUM(XSize) SXSize,SUM(TSize) STSize FROM (SELECT table_schema DB,
data_length DSize,index_length XSize,data_length+index_length TSize
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN
('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')) AAA
GROUP BY DB WITH ROLLUP) AA,(SELECT 3 pw) BB ORDER BY (SDSize+SXSize);
```

This query shows you the amount of disk space taken by Database by Storage Engine in GB

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(B.table_schema)+ISNULL(B.engine)=2,"Storage for All Databases",
IF(ISNULL(B.table_schema)+ISNULL(B.engine)=1,CONCAT("Storage for ",B.table_schema),
CONCAT(B.engine," Tables for ",B.table_schema))) Statistic,CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(
FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B')
"Data Size",CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),
' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size",CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/
POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size"
FROM (SELECT table_schema,engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,
SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')
AND engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY table_schema,engine WITH ROLLUP) B,
(SELECT 3 pw) A ORDER BY TSize;
```

The three previous queries I posted has a common feature : the subquery `(SELECT 3 pw)`

- If you use `(SELECT 0 pw)`, report is in Bytes
- If you use `(SELECT 1 pw)`, report is in KiloBytes
- If you use `(SELECT 2 pw)`, report is in MegaBytes
- If you use `(SELECT 3 pw)`, report is in GigaBytes
- If you use `(SELECT 4 pw)`, report is in TeraBytes
- If you use `(SELECT 5 pw)`, report is in PetaBytes (If you need this, post that result please !!!)

Comment: You should post questions like this in dba.stackexchange.com. I am in that forum as well.

Comment: oh! I dint know about that I will do it for sure next time.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name),
       CONCAT(ROUND(table_rows / 1000000, 2), 'M')                                    rows,
       CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                    DATA,
       CONCAT(ROUND(index_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                   idx,
       CONCAT(ROUND(( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') total_size,
       ROUND(index_length / data_length, 2)                                           idxfrac
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
ORDER  BY data_length + index_length DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

Reference [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/02/04/finding-out-largest-tables-on-mysql-server/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/show-table-status.html) to get the sizes for each table.

Answer (score 2):

This is the query I used after reading all your answers.

```
  SELECT table_name,round((data_length+index_length)/(1024 * 1024 *1024),2) table_size
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  ORDER BY data_length + index_length 
  DESC  limit 10;
```